# What is this error and where is wrong in React Native App with Expo.TypeError

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I got this error below. What is this error and where is wrong in my project?

> TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this._callListerners.bind')

IDE: Expo
React Native : 0.57
React-Navigation: 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed that with cleaning cash of react native.